# Empty array after reading text file

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, bufferedreader

It's fixed! Thanks to Edgar Boda.

I created a class that should read a text file and put that into an array:

```
private static String[] parts;

public static void Start() throws IOException{      
    InputStream instream = new FileInputStream("Storyline.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

    int numberOfLines=0, numberOfActions;


    String line = null, input="";

    while((line=buffreader.readLine())!=null){
        line=buffreader.readLine();
        input+=line;

    }
    parts=input.split(";");
}
```

But, when I try and output the array, it only contains one string. The last from the file, that I put in.

Here's the file I read from:

```
0;0;
Hello!;
Welcome!To this.;
56;56;
So;
```

I think it's something in the loop; but trying to put `parts[number]` in there doesn't work... Any suggestions?

Comment: And how are you printing your `array elements`?

Comment: I tried it with `System.out.println(parts[0])`. This outputted only the `So`, at the end of the file. If I tried `parts[1]`, I got an error that said that it didn't exist in the array.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please put a green check mark next to it, to let others know that is the correct solution.

Comment: @Bucco Yeah I know, but it was too fast... So I had to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to read the whole file into an String first maybe:

```
String line = null;
String input = "";
while((line=buffreader.readLine())!=null){
    input += line;
}

parts = input.split(";");
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem, although I had to put extra in the loop: `line=buffreader.readLine()`, because now `line` stays `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It *will* only contain the last line; you are reassigning `parts` every time:

```
parts = line.split(";");
```

This trashes the previous reference and reassigns a reference to a new array to it. A better way might be to use a `StringBuilder` and append the lines and then split later:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while((line=buffreader.readLine())!=null){
    stringBuilder.append(line);
}

parts = stringBuilder.toString().split(";");
```

This way you will get everything you want in *one* array. If you want to split everything such that you have *one* array *per* line, you will need `parts` to be a two-dimensional array. But the drawback is that you will need to know how many lines will be there in the file. Instead, you can use `List<String[]>` to keep track of your arrays:

```
List<String[]> lineParts = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while((line=buffreader.readLine())!=null){
    lineParts.add(line.split(";"));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought so... But if I try to put `parts[counter]`, in there, (counter will count with loop), it gives an error...

Comment: @ikhebgeenaccount Check out my update. One option is to use a `StringBuilder` to keep track of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the string array `parts` in every iteration of your `while` loop, so that's why it only contains the last line.

To store the entire file contents, with fields split, you'll need a 2-dimensional array, not a 1-dimensional array.  Assuming there are 5 lines in the file:

```
private static String[][] parts = new String[5][];
```

Then assign each split array to an element of `parts` each loop:

```
parts[i++]=line.split(";");  // Assuming you define "i" for the line number
```

Also, `split` by default discards trailing empty tokens.  To retain them, use the [two-arg overload of `split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) that takes a `limit` parameter.  Pass a negative number to retain all tokens.

```
parts[i++] = line.split(";", -1);
```